# K8S: securing GlusterFS

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I have a question on how to divide access to the same gluster for different K8S namespaces. Let's say, I have 3 different volumes (`vol-a`, `vol-b`, `vol-c`) in a gluster and I'd like to permit access to each of them for each of different namespaces (`namespace-a` - to `vol-a`, `namespace-b` - to `vol-b`, `namespace-c` - to `vol-c`).

Is that possible to implement such a scheme? Maybe there a way to authenticate a client of a gluster with some username and password? Is there a way to define these credentials in an endpoint configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you may want to use [Resource Quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/) per namespace for your cluster.

This will prevent each of your namespaces from requesting volumes from other namespaces.

Also, you can set the `claimRef namespace` field for Persistent Volumes in order to restrict them to only PVCs from particular namespace.

Please let me know if that was the case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Resource Quotas are exactly what I need.